# R knn variable selection

Tags: r, feature-selection, k-nearest-neighbour, caret

I have a data set that's 200k rows X 50 columns.  I'm trying to use a `knn` model on it but there is huge variance in performance depending on which variables are used (i.e., `rsqd` ranges from .01 (using all variables) to .98 (using only 5 variables)).

This kind of compounds my problem as now I need to determine `k` *and* which variables to use.

Is there a package in R that helps with selecting variables for a `knn` model, while tuning `k`?  I've looked at `rfe()` in `caret` but it seems to only be built for linear regression, `randomforest`, naive bayes, etc but no `knn`.

As an aside, I've tried manually building a loop to use the caret train function like this:

```
for(i in 2:50){
knnFit <- train(x[,i],y,...) ## trains model using single variable
}
```

My problem is that `knnFit$results` prints all of the results and `knnFit$bestTune` only prints the final parameter of `k`.

```
> data1 <- data.frame(col1=runif(20), col2=runif(20), col3=runif(20), col4=runif(20), col5=runif(20))
> bootControl <- trainControl(number = 1)
> knnGrid <- expand.grid(.k=c(2:5))
> set.seed(2)
> knnFit1 <- train(data1[,-c(1)], data1[,1]
+ , method = "knn", trControl = bootControl, verbose = FALSE,
+ tuneGrid = knnGrid )
> knnFit1 
20 samples
 4 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrap (1 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 20 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  RMSE   Rsquared
  2  0.485  0.124   
  3  0.54   0.369   
  4  0.52   0.241   
  5  0.528  0.232   

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 2. 

> knnFit1$results
      k      RMSE  Rsquared RMSESD RsquaredSD
    1 2 0.4845428 0.1241031     NA         NA
    2 3 0.5401009 0.3690569     NA         NA
    3 4 0.5197262 0.2410814     NA         NA
    4 5 0.5277939 0.2317607     NA         NA

> knnFit1$bestTune
      .k
    1  2
```

I need some way to print the RMSE/rsqd/other metric for the best single performing model (i.e., just "R-Squared: .91").

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is one of my problems with R.  What library is `train()` from?  Without the `library(...)` line in there, it's insanely difficult to figure this out in this case with a function as vaguely-named as `train`.  If convention was to call functions like lib.name::function() then this wouldn't be so hard...

Comment: @wordsforthewise: `train` is from the `caret` package.

Comment: yeah I should've been able to see that from the tags but didn't think to look there.   thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

knnFit1$results is actually a data.frame, so you can print all of the R-squared results with:

```
knnFit1$results$Rsquared
```

Or the R-squared result for just the best model:

```
knnFit1.sorted <- results[order(results$Rsquared),]
knnFit1.sorted[1,'Rsquared']
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: @screechOwl Glad to hear it! I love R `data.frame`s.